# cannot access files array after posting data via formData xhr request

Tags: javascript, php

I'm developing a script which is supposed to display an uploaded percentage for a file that is uploaded (pretty simple stuff).

I followed [**this**](https://gist.github.com/ebidel/2410898) example, and made few slight modifications security wise.

After reading all the comments on the git, I assumed that it would work perfectly fine - but for some reason, when I try to output the `$_FILES` array within **PHP**, it returns an empty array.

---

## Here are my scripts

**JavaScript (**`static.example.com/uploader.js`**):**

```
let formData = new FormData(),
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// file is defined earlier
formData.append("file", file);

xhr.open("POST", "//ajx.example.com/upload.php");
xhr.onprogress = function(e){
    console.log("Uploading");
}

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4){
        if(xhr.status == 200)
            console.log("Server response:", JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        else
            return console.error("There was an error.");
    }
}
xhr.send(formData);
```

**PHP** (`ajx.example.com/upload.php`**):**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com", false);
header("Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8", false);

/*
*    returns array(0){} 
*/
echo var_dump($_FILES);
die();
```

---

I have no idea why this is happening, and my code seems to be perfectly fine.

All help is appreciated,
Cheers.

**EDIT:** 

I have noticed that the uploader works fine on *some* files. `php.ini` is configured correctly for everything. But if I test out two **mp3** files (for example), one of the **mp3** files will not work. It's as if some files are corrupt - yet they aren't.

Comment: Is `this.file` defined?

Comment: @u_mulder indeed it is :) might comment that actually

Comment: What does the `var_dump($_POST);` returns?

Comment: @DavidR exactly the same thing :(

Comment: Does your `php.ini` has `file_uploads` set to `ON`?

Comment: How is `this.file`, or `file` defined? Note in the example you provide the file is in a FileList from the file input, `this.files[0]`. Also check your php config to make sure your max file / max post size will allow the size of the file you are trying to upload

Comment: @PatrickEvans `this` is a global identifier (this script is embedded within an object as a function).

Comment: @DavidR seems to be

Comment: Wasn't asking about `this` was asking how you defined your file variable.

Comment: @PatrickEvans oh, my mistake. `this.file = fileInput.files[0]`

Comment: Check your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` php.ini variables then, make sure they will accommodate the size of the file you are uploading.

Comment: @PatrickEvans check edit :)

Comment: As Patrick says, is it possible that some of your files are too large? There is an upload size limit. You state your php ini variables are "all correct" but then provide no direct evidence we can verify.

Comment: @ADyson if you check the edit, it states that **some** files work (same file type & roughly the same size) so my PHP ini is definitely correct. But yes, I have set all the limits to `150M` and allowed files to be uploaded.

Comment: "it states that some files work"...yes that was my point, that maybe the ones that didn't were falling foul of the limits. You didn't mention the sizes of your files or your limit setting values explicitly, you merely asserted that it was all correct without proving it so that anyone can check. 150M should be more than enough though. Do you perhaps get any kind of error in your JS console or network tools when you upload the files which don't appear to reach their destination?